# AngulsrJS выполнение функции после выполнение других асинхронных $http запросов

Tags: angularjs, http, асинхронность, promise

Пример одного из моих $http запросов в AngularJS (структура других аналогична)

```
$scope.getCurrentCareers=function () {
        var promise = $http({
            url: basePath + "/studentreg/getcurrentcareers",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'}
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.currentCareers=response.data;
        }, function errorCallback() {
            console.log("error");
        });
        return promise;
    };
```

В контроллере у меня нужно вызвать три разных сервиса, чтобы они выполнялись параллельно, а после того как последних из них(по времени) получит ответ - вызвать 4-ю функцию.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $scope.getCurrentCareers();
        $scope.getCurrentSpecializations();
        $scope.getCurrentCountryCity();
// после последнего ответа вызвать функцию $scope.myFunction();
          .then(
             function () {$scope.myFunction();
          )};
)};
```

Подскажите как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать либо [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)  из стандарта ECMAScript.
Либо сервис ангуляра [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

Пример нескольких запросов:

```
loadSomeInfo().then(function(something) {  
  loadAnotherInfo().then(function(another) {
    doSomethingOnThem(something, another);
  });
});
```

Переписать в такое:

```
$q.all([loadSomeInfo(), loadAnotherInfo()]).then(function (results) {
  doSomethingOnThem(results[0], results[1]);
});
```