# Как вызвать функцию ПОСЛЕ выполнения промисов?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, асинхронность, promise

Пишу свой первый проект на AngularJS. Приложение мониторит песочницу инстаграма по двум введеным хештегам, для каждого хаштега выводятся изображения сожержащие данный тег в соответствующие поля в представлении. Также есть результирующее поле для вывода результатов по совпадающим тегам, то есть если изображение сожержит оба введенных тега, то оно попадает также и в поле результата.

Есть функция, которая перебирает оба массива, в которые кладутся результаты http запроса по каждому из хештегов, ищет совпадение по id, кладет совпадающие элементы во временный массив, который потом чистится от дублирующих элементов и окончательный результат кладется в результирующий массив, из которого происходит вывод изображений в представление в поле результата.

У меня не получается сделать вызов этой функции ПОСЛЕ того как отработают оба http запроса и массивы заполнятся объектами из ответа, чтобы функции было с чем работать. Что бы я ни делал, вызов функции происходит раньше выполнения асинхронных запросов. Пробовал делать как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611145/angulsrjs-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-http-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2), использовал как `Promise.all()` так и ангуляровский `$q`, все равно вызов функции отбора результатов происходит раньше чем приходит ответ от api.

Фактори выполняющая запрос к api:

```
angular.module('requestToApi', [])
  .constant('clientID', 'myClientID')
  .factory('getResponseApi', function(clientID, $http) {
    return {
      request: function (tag) {
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent',
          params: {access_token: clientID}
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

Контроллер:

```
angular.module("app").controller("appCtrl", ['$scope', 'getResponseApi', '$q', '$interval',
  function($scope, getResponseApi, $q, $interval, $stateProvider) {

    $scope.dataStorage1 = [];
    $scope.dataStorage2 = [];
    $scope.commonDataStorage = [];

    $scope.tag1 = "nature";
    $scope.tag2 = "mountains";

    $scope.getDataLeft = function() {
      getResponseApi.request($scope.tag1).then(function(response) {
        $scope.dataStorage1 = response.data.data;
      });
    };

    $scope.getDataRight = function() {
      getResponseApi.request($scope.tag2).then(function(response) {
        $scope.dataStorage2 = response.data.data;
      });
    };

    $scope.appStart = function() {
      $q.all([$scope.getDataLeft(), $scope.getDataRight()]).then(function() {
        getCommonData();
      })
    };

    $scope.appStart();

    function getCommonData() {
      let commonArray = [],
      val1, val2;

      for(val1 of $scope.dataStorage1) {
        for (val2 of $scope.dataStorage2) {
          if (val1.caption.id === val2.caption.id) {
            commonArray.unshift(val1);

            $scope.commonDataStorage = (commonArray.filter((item) => itemCheck(item)));
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function itemCheck(item) {
      let temp = [];

      if (temp.indexOf(item.caption.id) === -1) {
        temp.unshift(item.caption.id);
        return true
      }

      return false;
    }

  }]);
```

По идее вся магия должна происходить здесь,

```
$scope.appStart = function() {
  $q.all([$scope.getDataLeft(), $scope.getDataRight()]).then(function() {
    getCommonData();
  })
};
```

но магия не происходит. Подскажите что делаю не так?

Так же хотелось бы вынести функцию `getCommonData` в отдельный factory, можно ли это сделать если она использует `$scope`?

Comment: могу ошибаться, но мне кажется Вам надо функции `getData*` сделать промисами что бы *магия* работала

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$http возвращает промис в angular, в `getResponseApi` вы используете его правильно, а `getData*` не возвращает ничего.

Вариант перевозврата промиса от `getResponseApi`

```
$scope.getDataLeft = function () {
    return getResponseApi.request($scope.tag1);
};

$scope.getDataRight = function () {
    return getResponseApi.request($scope.tag2);
};

$scope.appStart = function () {
    $q.all([$scope.getDataLeft(), $scope.getDataRight()]).then(function (response1, response2) {
        $scope.dataStorage1 = response1.data.data;
        $scope.dataStorage2 = response2.data.data;
        getCommonData();
    })
};
```

И вариант с новым промисом в `getData*`:

```
$scope.getDataLeft = function () {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        getResponseApi.request($scope.tag1).then(function (response) {
            $scope.dataStorage1 = response.data.data;
            resolve();
        });
    });
};

$scope.appStart = function () {
    $q.all([$scope.getDataLeft(), $scope.getDataRight()]).then(function () {
        getCommonData();
    })
};
```

Comment: Взял вариант с новым промисом, спасибо! Может быть по второму вопросу подскажете? Можно ли `getCommonData` вынести в отдельный factory если она использует `$scope`?

Comment: @rocket27 не уверен, но подозреваю, что передавая в сервис переменную она будет не указателем а клоном. Если только как-то так - `$scope.commonDataStorage = getCommonData($scope.dataStorage1, $scope.dataStorage2)` и в сервисе возвращать результат